# Module in list can't be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, cryptography, crypt

I know that this could be marked as a duplicate, but hear me out! 
The questions like this one are *horribly* out of date and no longer apply to my needs!

I used `help("Modules")`to get a list of all installed modules.
The module I was looking for, `"crypt"` was in the list.
When I tried to import it in the shell and in a new file, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import crypt
  File "C:\Users\Work\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\crypt.py", line 3, in <module>
import _crypt
ImportError: No module named '_crypt'
```

**Note**:
I did not call it with an underscore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run it on Windows -- crypt is a Unix-only library.

https://docs.python.org/dev/library/crypt.html

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense. Why doesn't Windows have it?

Comment: Because the underlying service it relies on, the crypt(3) routine, doesn't exist in Windows.